# What's the difference between a higher sheaf on a regular ($1$-) site and a sheaf on a $2$- (or $\infty$-)site?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, higher-category-theory

A higher site's coverage satisfies

> If $\left\{f_: U' \rightarrow U\right\}$ is a covering family and $g: V \rightarrow U$ is a morphism, then there exists a covering family $\left\{h: V' \rightarrow V\right\}$ such that the composite $g\circ h$ factors through $f$ **up to higher morphisms**.

instead of the usual condition where strict equality $g\circ h=f$ is involved.

Also a higher sheaf takes value in higher categories, for example, $(2,1)$-sheaf is a stack (category fibered in groupoid).

I understand the higher descent when the site is a regular one (the $3$-cocycle codition involved in the descent for usual stack is nothing but a $2$-morphism and when the sheaf goes higher the $n$-cocycle codition gets imposed; see http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/descent#AsGluing).

But how exactly is a higher sheaf on a higher site different from that on a regular site?

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for Mathoverflow.

Comment: I don't really agree with Moishe; the question's just rather vague. Do you know the definition of a sheaf on a higher site?

Comment: @KevinArlin I'm not sure about that definition. nLab doesn't elaborate it in detail.

Comment: What about http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/(infinity,1)-sheaf or http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/2-sheaf ?

Comment: @KevinArlin oh yes the first one helps a lot!